# Why does IE interpret a tab as 8 spaces and Notepad++ interpret as 4 spaces

Tags: javascript, text

IE interprets a tab as 8 spaces. Notepad++  interprets it as 4 spaces.

This makes my code look messy and now I have to fix it.

I would think a tab would be a universal length.  Is this set via the text encoding.

Is a tab stored the same way and just interpreted differently?

Comment: tab is interpreted by the program opening the file. and in notepad++ you can even set how many spaces a tab should be.. so: no. tab is simply the ascii charechter 9. evey program can diced what to do with this. (generally its the makers decision).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [CSS standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html) dictates tabs at 8 spaces, in section 16.6.1, second paragraph, item 2:

> Tab stops occur at points that are multiples of 8 times the width of a
>   space (U+0020) rendered in the block's font from the block's starting
>   content edge.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is. If you want consistency, just use 4 spaces instead of a tab.

Answer (score 3):

A tab is nothing more than a character in memory. How it is rendered, depends on the editor/viewer/etc, and often you can configure the width as a setting in the application.

Because of this, you'd be better off using spaces, so that everyone sees the same thing.

Answer (score -1):

Tabs are evil, because there's no universal standard many spaces equal a tab.
For the current problem, you can adjust your setting in Notepad++  to what you need

In notepad++  in the settings menu  -> Preference -> (tabs) Language Menu/ Tabs Settings

Comment: I'd argue the exact opposite.  Tabs allow the viewer to determine exactly how much spacing they think is appropriate for their own comfort.

Comment: I prefer to type a tabs instead of 4 spaces, me too, when I work a personnal file/project. But since not all  softwares let you configure the "tabs = X space", I prefer to use space if I need to share the file

Answer (score -2):

Tabs are evil. The common best practice in most languages is to convert tabs to spaces.

Reason being that, as you noticed, tabs are not a standard. Spaces, however, are.

Comment: They are not evil, they are just poor misunderstood souls. :-)

Comment: A tab lets the reader of the sourcecode decide how much it is idented, where a fixed number of spaces does not. A tab is a semantics and not represantition.

Comment: tabs vs spaces debates are as productive as religion vs atheism in my opinion

Comment: Esailija, exactly! hence my joke! This is definitely not a thing we want to dive into, especially on comments. ;-) Tabs involve individual preferences, and preferences generally involve subjective opinions. ps.: I didn't vote it down, I don't even have other votes today! I'm exhausted.